# How to create a list of arrays from multiple same-size vectors

Tags: python-3.x

I am attempting to create a list of arrays from 2 vectors.

I have a dataset I'm reading from a .csv file and need to pair each value with a 1 to create a list of arrays.

```
import numpy as np
Data = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]) #this is actually a column in a .csv file, but simplified it for the example
#do something here
output = ([1,1], [1,2], [1,3], [1,4], [1,5]) #2nd column in each array is the data, first is a 1
```

I've tried to use numpy concatenate and vstack, but they don't give me exactly what I'm looking for.
Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can form the output using a list comprehension:

```
data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
output = [[1, item] for item in data]
```

This will output:

```
[[1, 1], [1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 4], [1, 5]]
```